# Error: Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load. In SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I had installed SQL Server 2008 R2, the installation was succesful. But I can't open the Management Studio because this error is shown:

```
Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load.
```

Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I would start troubleshooting by using SysInternals Filemon and determining what it is trying to load from the file system. May be .dll load errors, etc. Also this question is more appropriate for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 13):

You need to rename or delete the Registry Key for,

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Read in detail on :

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2012/01/04/solution-for-package-microsoft-sql-management-studio-package-failed-to-load/

Answer (score 3):

Before re-installing software etc, you might just perform the following simple check.

Right click on the short-cut you use to launch SQL Server Management Studio, then ensure that `Start in` is set to the same PATH as `Target`

e.g. if  Target is set to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe
```

then `Start in` should be set to the same path (minus the filename) i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
```

(On a PC which I was given at work, 'Start in' was blank and this gave the same error as reported in the above posts.)

Answer (score 1):

From a first look at the log, your installation appears to be corrupt as `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll` is failing to load.

Can you please check to see if `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll` is in the GAC?

If it is, please run the fusion log (you should find this under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<sdk version>\bin`). Go to settings and turn on "log bind errors to disk" and then try running VS. The log file should tell you where the assembly binding failure.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues, started to happen to me out of the blue.
Tried probably everything I could find on the network without success.

I am running **Windows 7, and what finally helped was installing Service Pack 1**
(I hadn't had it before).

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'Repair' feature of the 'SQL Server Installation Center' to repair <Shared Tools>, rather than an instance. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a Windows 2008 r2 server. The solution was to right-click on the icon and select 'Run as Administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'Repair' feature of the 'SQL Server Installation Center' to repair the instance. It worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error due to managment studio did not detect dot net framework hence uninstall dot net 4 and reinstall it.
I tried that , it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, I had same problem for sql server 2008 r2 release

- Renamed HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
- Reinstall SQL server
- Repairer SQL server
- Reinstall management studio for 2008 r2

All above did not help but new fresh and latest management studio installation helped and works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

It's worked for me after delete Local user profile. (Logoff and login as Admin delete user profile and re-login).